# How do I embed a <script>?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-advertising-api

I'm very new to Reactjs. I have code from amazon to embed an add, but it only gives me  versions which from what I understand I can't use in React. Is there a work around?

Amazon code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "***";
amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "bottom";
amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "US";
amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "Dog Toys";
amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
amzn_assoc_linkid = "***";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

Comment: what do you mean `can't use in React` ? could you elaborate more?

Comment: that is just a <Script> being run, just make it a function.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699310/how-can-i-add-amazone-advertisement-script-inside-reactjs-component

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>

AmazonEmbededCode(){
    amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
    amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
    amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "***";
    amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "bottom";
    amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
    amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
    amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
    amzn_assoc_region = "US";
    amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
    amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "Dog Toys";
    amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
    amzn_assoc_linkid = "***";
 }
```

and you need to just call this function in your div

```
<div className="amazon-div" onLoad={this.AmazonEmbededCode()}>
    embed code here...
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused about where I put that top "<script> though